# Pandas DataFrame drop tuple or list of columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, tuples

When using the `drop` method for a `pandas.DataFrame` it accepts lists of column names, but not tuples, despite the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)  saying that "*list-like*" arguments are acceptable. Am I reading the documentation incorrectly, as I would expect my MWE to work.

**MWE**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({k: range(5) for k in list('abcd')})
df.drop(['a', 'c'], axis=1) # Works
df.drop(('a', 'c'), axis=1) # Errors
```

**Versions** - Using Python 2.7.12, Pandas 0.20.3.

Comment: what about: `df.drop(list(('a', 'c')), axis=1)`?

Comment: I think that this is a doc bug.

Comment: @MaxU, that is the work around I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas treats tuples as multi-index values, so try this instead:

```
In [330]: df.drop(list(('a', 'c')), axis=1)
Out[330]:
   b  d
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
```

here is an example for deleting **rows** (axis=0 - default) in the multi-index DF:

```
In [342]: x = df.set_index(np.arange(len(df), 0, -1), append=True)

In [343]: x
Out[343]:
     a  b  c  d
0 5  0  0  0  0
1 4  1  1  1  1
2 3  2  2  2  2
3 2  3  3  3  3
4 1  4  4  4  4

In [344]: x.drop((0,5))
Out[344]:
     a  b  c  d
1 4  1  1  1  1
2 3  2  2  2  2
3 2  3  3  3  3
4 1  4  4  4  4

In [345]: x.drop([(0,5), (4,1)])
Out[345]:
     a  b  c  d
1 4  1  1  1  1
2 3  2  2  2  2
3 2  3  3  3  3
```

So when you specify `tuple` Pandas treats it as a multi-index label

Answer (score 3):

There is problem with tuples select `Multiindex`:

```
np.random.seed(345)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('abcde'), list('cdefg')])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,5)), columns=mux)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e
   c  d  e  f  g
0  8  0  3  9  8
1  4  3  4  1  7
2  4  0  9  6  3
3  8  0  3  1  5

df = df.drop(('a', 'c'), axis=1)
print (df)
   b  c  d  e
   d  e  f  g
0  0  3  9  8
1  3  4  1  7
2  0  9  6  3
3  0  3  1  5
```

Same as:

```
df = df[('a', 'c')]
print (df)
0    8
1    4
2    4
3    8
Name: (a, c), dtype: int32
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this to delete column of tuples

```
del df3[('val1', 'val2')]
```

and it got deleted.